# How to access variable outside the function in which it was defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to use the variable that is defined within a jQuery click function. I know the difference between global and local variables, but creating the variable outside the function doesn't seem to help.

```
var $genre;
$('#search').click(function() {
    $genre = $(this).attr('value');
});
console.log($genre);
```

There has to be some simple solution that I'm just not thinking of.

Comment: Well, since it's being set in a click event, it won't have a value until you trigger the click event...

Comment: Are you using `console.log` inside another function/handler? Because the way you are doing it now means `console.log` will not get executed when the click handler is triggered.

Comment: it will just print `undefined`

Comment: You are trying to eat a pizza before it gets delivered!

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 value scopes in JS: Function and Global

Meaning that value is inside the .click callback and will only exist after is clicked. Undefined is actually a type in JS, means the variable exist but has no value assigned yet.

My suspicion is that you a thinking that code will execute synchronously, but the function click will only be called when... click

Comment: Yes, log the variable UNTIL is clicked... you'll see the value then

Comment: "There are only 2 value scopes in JS: Function and Global", wrong. There's also a block scope. https://gist.github.com/StephanBijzitter/5dc3d2b0dd8ce959727b6184d8278875

Comment: Noup, the let keyword is a fix in for the fact that there was never a block scope in JS. It is also only implemented in EC6.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let  - Pretty much the reason IIFE where used as a de facto block substitute for years...

Comment: "Variables declared by let have as their scope the block in which they are defined" Block scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the 'value' in the click event. Hence, the value will be assigned only when you click on "#search". So the the console.log statement will not have any value.

Instead try this.

```
var $genre;
$('#search').click(function() {
    $genre = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log($genre);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- The code is actually doing exactly what you wanted to to deal with the variable but within the function you are not logging it to the console.
- One thing I noticed is that you are also accessing the "value" attribute by using $(this).attr('value'). If you are attempting to get the value of an input which is what I'm assuming was the original intent, [Jquery has a built in function to get the value of an input.](http://api.jquery.com/val/) .

The code to make both of these changes I mentioned is below!

```
var $genre;

$('#search').click(function() {
    //sets the variable to the value of the input
    $genre = $(this).val();

    //prints the variable to the console everytime that the element is clicked
    console.log($genre);
});
```